# Testing the Messaging module on localhost

Tags: email, smtp, orchardcms, iis-express

I am trying to get mail working from `Orchard CMS`. I run `IIS Express` in the `DEV` environment. I do have local `IIS` on my machine as well `(W7 x64).` I am struggling to tie this all together to see if the mail is generated and has the correct content.

I have tried to set u a `virtual SMTP server` in `IIS` with the option to deliver the mail to designated folder. But the sending of the mail from `Orchard` is not picked up.

Any tips and tricks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do some hacking into the code of the Orchard.Mail module. I have changed the line in EmailMessagingChannel.cs:

```
smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
```

into:

```
smtpClient.PickupDirectoryLocation = somedirectory;
smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectory;
```

That worked. Should this not be in some setting that one can turn on or off while developing?